# Docker to localhost

Tags: iptables, docker, nat

I am using a framework which sets up multiple docker containers and starts them up.

I wanted to update the source code for one of them but do not want to keep rebuilding the docker image. So, I thought of developing the code locally and point the configuration to my localhost.

However, a service running on docker is unable to connect to my local instance (I am able to curl it just fine outside docker). After some digging around, I was able to get the `docker.host.internal` mapping so that the container knows the host IP, but that didn't work either.

I suspect the firewall (iptables) may be blocking traffic.

1. How can I confirm if iptables is blocking traffic? Are there any logs that I can check to confirm my hypothesis?
2. I think I need to add a DNAT rule, is that right? (ex: `iptables -A DOCKER -i <docker nic> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6060 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:6060`; although this didn't help either)
3. If I run an iptables command like above, does the change take effect immediately or iptables be restarted somehow to take effect?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Are you able to reach the app running on your localhost from any IP address other than a loopback address, or is it only listening on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: It is a publicly reachable IP. I'm not able to reach the app from the public IP with the correct port specified. To add some more information, the IP is on a cloud server and the actual server is running on my local machine. I've set up a reverse ssh tunnel using `ssh -R 6060:localhost:6060 <host>`. Once the tunnel is set up I'm able to `curl localhost:6060` from within my virtual IP but am unable to access it from public.

Comment: Thanks a lot, BMitch, it inspired a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested with NAT, but what I ended up doing was setting `GatewayPorts=clientspecified` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting sshd.

Then, all I had to do was set up my reverse tunnel using `ssh -R <docker host ip>:6060:localhost:6060 <host>`. This would essentially avoid binding the port to the loopback interface, and instead, bind it to the docker ip directly.

This way, I can develop on my local machine for testing quick changes while not having to rebuild docker images. Also, this way, I will not be allowing port access to public so it's fairly secure. :)